# wordpress: pie register overriding login redirect

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, redirect

I downloaded and activated pie register.

Since doing that my redirect has changed.

I have the following function in my functions.php:

```
function redirect_to_front_page($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    return (is_array($user->roles) && in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) ? site_url() : site_url();
} 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_front_page', 10, 3);
```

However, I think that pie register might be overriding it somehow and redirecting me to the dashboard  instead.

Does anyone know how I might be able to stop this pie-register redirect after login override?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the third parameter of your "add_filter" line to a number higher than 10.

I.e:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_front_page', 20, 3);
```

That parameter specifies the priority of the filter, so adding a higher priority to your filter should override the filter set in the Pie Register plugin.